# index a column of dataframe regarding other columns and

Tags: python, dataframe, indexing, widget

I have provided this data frame, 
[image]

[image]

as you see I have 3 index chapter, ParaIndex, (paragraph index) and Sentindex (sententcesindex), I have 70 chapters, 1699 Paragraph, and 6999 sentences

so each of them starts from the beginning (0 or 1 ), the problem is that I want to make a widget to call a "specific sentence" which placed in a specific paragraph of a chapter. something like this

https://towardsdatascience.com/interactive-controls-for-jupyter-notebooks-f5c94829aee6
but for extracting specific sentences in the specific paragraph of the specific chapter

I think I should have another index  (like ChapParaSent ABBREVIATION for all) or even multidimensions index which show that this sentence where exactly  placed

any idea how can I provide that using ipywidget
https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Using%20Interact.html

```
@interact
def showDetail( Chapter=(1,70),ParaIndex=(0,1699),SentIndex=(0,6999)):
    return df.loc[(df.Chapter == Chapter) & (df.ParaIndex==ParaIndex)&(df.SentIndex==SentIndex)]
```

the problem with this is since we do not know each chapter has how many paragraphs has as well as and we do not know in each paragraph SentIndex the index to start from which number most of the time we have no result.

the aim is to adopt this (or define a new index) in a way that  with changing the bar buttons we have always one unique sentence

for example, here I have the result:

[image]

but when I changed to this :

[image: [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CdKX0.jpg]
I do not have any result, the REASON is obvious because we do not have any index as 1-2-1 since, in chapter 1, Paragraph index 2: Sentindex starts from 2!

One solution I saw that it was a complete definition of a multidimensional data frame but I need something easier that I can use by ipywidget...

many many thanks

Comment: so you dont really care about the index? you just want the i-th sentence from the n-th paragraph in the m-th chapter?

Comment: exactly!  M-Th chapter n-paragraph od that and I sentence of that : ) at the end I want to choose it by that widget. any ideas?

Comment: @SyntaxError  many tnx

Comment: "that with changing the bar buttons we have always one unique sentence"

so the name "show_articles_more_than" is not correct... right?

Comment: oh, sorry....you are right...

Comment: @SyntaxError edit has been done! any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Im sure there is a easier solution out there but that works I guess.

```
import pandas as pd

data = [
dict(Chapter=0, ParaIndex=0, SentIndex=0, content="0"),
dict(Chapter=1, ParaIndex=1, SentIndex=1, content="a"),
dict(Chapter=1, ParaIndex=1, SentIndex=2, content="b"),
dict(Chapter=2, ParaIndex=2, SentIndex=3, content="c"),
dict(Chapter=2, ParaIndex=2, SentIndex=4, content="d"),
dict(Chapter=2, ParaIndex=3, SentIndex=5, content="e"),
dict(Chapter=3, ParaIndex=4, SentIndex=6, content="f"),
    ]


df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

[image]

```
def showbyindex(target_chapter, target_paragraph, target_sentence):

    df_chapter = df.loc[df.Chapter==target_chapter]
    unique_paragraphs = df_chapter.ParaIndex.unique()
    paragraph_idx = unique_paragraphs[target_paragraph]

    df_paragraph = df_chapter.loc[df.ParaIndex==paragraph_idx]

    return df_paragraph.iloc[target_sentence]



showbyindex(target_chapter=2, target_paragraph=0, target_sentence=1)
```

[image]

**Edit:**
If you want the sliders only to be within a valid range you can define IntSliders for your interact decorator:

```
chapter_slider = widgets.IntSlider(min=0, max=max(df.Chapter.unique()), step=1, value=0)
paragraph_slider = widgets.IntSlider(min=0, max=1, step=1, value=0)
sentence_slider = widgets.IntSlider(min=0, max=1, step=1, value=0)


@interact(target_chapter=chapter_slider, target_paragraph=paragraph_slider, target_sentence=sentence_slider)
```

Now you have to check the valid number of paragraphs/sentences within your showbyindex function and set the sliders value/max accordingly.

```
if(...):
    paragraph_slider.max = ...
...
```

Comment: thank you for your response, all start from zero, but chapter starts from 1. unfortunate It does not work .. it says ```single positional indexer is out-of-bounds```

Comment: I paly around with - also...it does not work, but the idea looks correct to define sub-data frame ...but it dies not to work now

Comment: well... if e.g. chapter 1 has only 1 paragraph and you want to get the second one it wont work. Same goes for sentences and chapters of course

Comment: I see, actually that is my question since I want to go through sentences using that widget. I  think I need to define a new index or...I want to write a program that for each chapter goes through only correct number of a paragraph index  and for each paragraph go thorugh  correct sentecnes index

Comment: any idea ? :) still..I really do not know